# What does 二千〇九 mean?

Tags: translation, number

二千〇九. A friend won't tell me what it means. The signs could be backwards.

Comment: it means 2009..

Comment: we speak and write it as 两千零九 only.

Answer (score 4):

〇 is a legitimate Chinese character that you can find in dictionaries. Basically it's just a simplified form of 零, or the character version of 0, with some differences:

- 〇 doesn't have other meanings of 零 besides "zero"
- 〇 can also serve as a placeholder for an unknown character
- According to 《GB/T 15835-2011 General rules for writing numerals in public texts》, 零 is for measuring while 〇 is for numbering. So TECHNICALLY they are not interchangeable.

[image: GB/T 15835-2011]

[image: GB/T 15835-2011]

The other 3 characters are easy, 二 = 2, 千 = thousand, 九 = 9, so 二千〇九 means 2009.

Answer (score 2):

二 -> 2 （can also use 两）

千 -> thousand

〇 -> 0 (can also use 零)

九 -> 9

to sum up, 二千〇九 -> 2009